# Existing package can not be found during configure

Tags: linux, installation

I try to install `icewm` form this [project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/multicursor-wm). I have two computers, first with Centos 6.5, second with Centos 7. I installed `icewm` on Centos 6.5. But I can not install `icewm` on Centos 7.

```
./configure --disable-xfreetype --enable-corefonts --without-imlib --disable-xinerama

...
checking for XpmReadFileToPixmap in -lXpm... no
configure: error: libXpm can not be found
```

But package `libXpm` is installed. Centos 6.5 and Centos 7 have got this package in the same location :

```
/usr/lib64/libXpm.so.4.11.0
/usr/lib64/libXpm.so.4
/usr/lib64/libXpm.so
```

Also both centos have got `xpm` in pkg-config.

```
pkg-config --list-all | grep xpm
xpm                        Xpm - X Pixmap Library
```

So why I can not install icewm on Centos 7 ? How to solve it?

**EDIT**

U use `--disable-xinerama` because Xinerama also can not be found despite it is installed.

**EDIT2**

I installed all X library:

```
yum install xorg-x11*
yum install libX*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found following log in config.log file:

```
/bin/ld: cannot find -lsupc++
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I changed -lsupc++ to -lstdc++ in 9996 line in configure file.

It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the library to configure:

```
root> LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib64" ./configure --disable-xfreetype --enable-corefonts --without-imlib --disable-xinerama
```

`LDFLAGS` is basically an Environment Variable.

**UPDATE**

Try running these before running the above command.

```
root> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib64"

root> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64
```

I am really not sure, why `configure` cannot take this default location.

Comment: It gives the same result.

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: It still gives the same result.

Comment: Last try, write `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of `LD_LIBRARY_FLAGS`. It was my mistake, updated my answer.

Comment: It still gives the same result.

Comment: I give up. Sorry.

Comment: Tkanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `devel` package for any library that you are compiling against.

In this instance, you need to install `libXpm-devel`:

```
# yum install libXpm-devel
```

Comment: It is installed

Comment: I installed all X library. `yum install libX*` and `yum install xorg-x11*`

Comment: That's odd. I've just `configure`'d `icewm` development and maintenance branches that I downloaded with `cvs` from sourceforge and it worked for both. Where did you get your source from?

Comment: Link to source is in first line in my question. There is modified icewm by Princeton University.

Comment: That modified version works for me - I'm not being very helpful here! I can only suggest you check all dependancies are installed. Sorry :-(

Comment: If I command `yum install libXpm-devel` I get `Package libXpm-devel-3.5.10-5.1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do` So this dependency is installed.

Comment: All very odd.  I've just fired up an Amazon EC2 RHEL 7 instance and after `# yum install automake autoconf gcc-c++ libX11-devel libXpm-devel` it ran the `configure` script with the options as show in your question. I'm stumped!  If you can't get it to compile on your machine, then I can only suggest you try to create a RPM from source using the `Copr` build system or install a VM and build a RPM on that.  Once you have a RPM, you can install it on your main machine.